# Liferay Build Services failed

Tags: liferay, portal

I've created a configuration for the Liferay Service Builder. After this I tried to build services, but I received the following error:

```
Buildfile: C:\LiferayNew\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\guestbook-portlet\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
C:\LiferayNew\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\guestbook-portlet\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\LiferayNew\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\build-common-portlet.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\LiferayNew\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-plugin.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\LiferayNew\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common.xml:60: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\LiferayNew\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-ivy.xml:71: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\LiferayNew\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-ivy.xml:55: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${ivy.jar.url}

Total time: 1 second.
```

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Did you delete the file `liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build.properties` or modified it in any way?

Comment: No, I don't delete this file. I'am very new in Liferay. Now, I delete      liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4 and liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2 and Liferay IDE. I create all new and then I will create a new portlet.

Comment: Check for ivy.jar.url in build.properties it should start with specified protocol like http

Comment: Normally, it should look like ivy.jar.url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.version}/ivy-${ivy.version}.jar

Comment: In build.<username>.properties  is given two definitions of ivy.jar.url, One definition is given in Comment.
#ivy.jar.url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.version}/ivy-${ivy.version}.jar
ivy.jar.url=http://cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-snapshots-ce/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/${ivy.version}/org.apache.ivy-${ivy.version}.jar